# Python ImportError: cannot import name 'version' from 'packaging' (transformers)

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

when I'm trying to simply `import transformers` I receive this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'version' from 'packaging' (C:\Users\miria\packaging.py)

Can anyone help me solve this?

[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHMPL.png)

Comment: Which version of transformers have you installed?

Comment: The version is 4.3.3 - thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you please add the whole error stacktrace to your question?

Comment: I added it above

Comment: It has also worked before, that's why I am really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is one of those cases where you have a bad naming. Maybe your file (or something inside your code) has a name that is overlapping one of the references you are trying to get. For example, if you are importing a certain module named "kivy" and your file is named "kivy", then the code will go after your file instead of the actual package you are trying to import.

if that's the case, try changing the name and the problem will be solved.

Comment: It was a naming conflict indeed! Thanks!